# Accessing web directory IIS from asp.net webapp IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, directory

So, I've been trying to give my web application read access to files in root/documents folder that I have created. I don't want the public to have access to this folder. Have managed to lock out public users through the documents folder authentication setting by disabling the anonymous authentication setting.

Having much larger problems giving the web app read access to files in that folder. Have added the apppool into the read folder permisions of the documents folder but still getting access denied messages.

Just wondering if there's anything else that may be affecting the applications access to the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding NETWORKSERVICE as a reader to the folder.

On the other hand, you can try using [impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and give read access to impoersonated user.

Comment: Thanks Anton, we did finally figure it out and yes using impersonation and adding some location authorization restrictions in the web config worked a treat. The app pool seems to be a little more difficult to implement successfully. For other users of stackoverflow please also refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx along with Antons link for the solution.